# How can we use custom iterables with string.join()?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, join, string-operations

The `join()` method for srings seems to work just fine for `list`s of strings and other built-in iterables. However, when I define my own iterables, `join()` cooperate. How can be write an iterable which `join()` is happy to have?

```
class IterATOR: # iter-ATOR
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 0
    def __next__(self):
        self.x += 1
        if self.x > 4:
            raise StopIteration()
        return 'hello world'

class IterABLE: # iter-ABLE
    def __iter__(self):
        return IterATOR()


print(30 * '#', 'BEGIN TEST ONE', 30 * '#')
gable = IterABLE()
gator = iter(gable)
try:
    while True:
        print(next(gator))
except StopIteration as exc:
    print(exc)


print(30 * '#', 'BEGIN TEST TWO', 30 * '#')
gable = IterABLE()
for elem in gable:
    print(elem)


print(30 * '#', 'BEGIN TEST THREE', 30 * '#')

lyst = [str(x) for x in range(0, 5)]
# tcs: test cases
tcs = [lyst, IterABLE(), iter(IterABLE()), IterATOR(), lyst, iter(lyst)]

for tc in tcs: # for test case in test cases:
    try:
         print(type(tc).__name__.ljust(20), end ='')
         merged_str = ''.join(tc)
         print(" was a success:".ljust(20), repr(merged_str))
    except Exception as exc:
        print(" was a failure:".ljust(20), str(exc))
```

The output for test three is:

```
############################## BEGIN TEST THREE ##############################
list                 was a success:      '01234'
IterABLE             was a failure:      'IterATOR' object is not iterable
IterATOR             was a failure:      can only join an iterable
IterATOR             was a failure:      can only join an iterable
list                 was a success:      '01234'
list_iterator        was a success:      '01234'
```

Comment: You forgot to implement the `__iter__` method in `IterATOR`.

Comment: `def __iter__(self):
        return self` in `IterATOR`: done